# WebSockets + Apache and Nginx in “reverse proxy mode” + SSL/secure

Tags: nginx, ssl, apache-2.4, php-fpm, websocket

As I had tried to connect PHP WebSocket from socketme.io through HTTP, since it was successful and again after loading certificates and making HTTPS it didn't work.

As my hosting server's nginx is configured to work in proxy mode

When website URL is opened in browser basically this is what it happens as follows:

1. *Client request comes to front-end Nginx asking for some resource (.html page, .php page, image, javascript, etc). Nginx in our hosting server works on TCP ports: 80 - http, 443 - https.*
2. *Nginx checks if it has the resource already in its cache.*
3. *If the resource is cached, Nginx returns the cached content.*
4. *If the resource is not cached or if the dynamic page (e.g. index.php) is requested, Nginx proxies (forwards) the request to back-end server - Apache. Apache in our hosting server works on TCP ports: 7080 - http, 7081 - https. Then Nginx caches static content - HTML, images, js, css.*

Nginx listen on port 80 for incoming connections and handle the SSL. Nginx will forward incoming connections to PHP-FPM for your regular website and if it detects a connection is a WebSocket connection and  proxying the  connection to the running Ratchet application on a port 8080 and then javascript could then connect via wss:/my.domain.com

On consoling from the browser

```
var conn = new WebSocket('wss://my.domain.com:8080'); 
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

1. > WebSocket connection to 'wss://my.domain.com:8080/' failed: WebSocket
   >   opening handshake timed out
2. > wss://my.domain.com:8080/wss WebSocket connection to
   >   'wss://my.domain.com:8080/wss' failed: WebSocket opening handshake
   >   timed out
3. > wss://my.domain.com:8080/websocket WebSocket connection to
   >   'wss://my.domain.com:8080/websocket' failed: WebSocket opening
   >   handshake timed out
4. > wss://my.domain.com/websocket:8080 WebSocket connection to
   >   'wss://my.domain.com/websocket:8080' failed: Error in connection
   >   establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
5. > wss://my.domain.com/wss:8080 WebSocket connection to
   >   'wss://my.domain.com/wss:8080' failed: Error in connection
   >   establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

   ```
   jQuery(function($){
       // Websocket_Controller
       var websocket_server = new WebSocket("wss://my.domain.com:8080");
       websocket_server.onopen = function(e) {
         websocket_server.send(
            ...
         );
       };

       websocket_server.onerror = function(e) {
         // Errorhandling
         ...
       }

       websocket_server.onmessage = function(e) {

           ...
       }
   }
   ```

I have a ratchet chat server file

```
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface  {

    ...
}

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(new WsServer(new Chat())),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        location /wss {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Proxy "";
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://my.domain.com:8080;
        }

        location /websocket {  
            proxy_pass http://my.domain.com:8080; ## WSPHP listening port
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400;
           }
    }
}


# override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#   /etc/apache2/
#   |-- apache2.conf
#   |   `--  ports.conf
#   |-- mods-enabled
#   |   |-- *.load
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   |-- conf-enabled
#   |   `-- *.conf
#   `-- sites-enabled
#       `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300

#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf


# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#   AllowOverride None
#   Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

I have tried to reload the nginx after modification as

```
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
/etc/init.d/nginx start
/etc/init.d/nginx stop
systemctl reload nginx
service nginx reload
nginx -s reload
pkill -HUP nginx
```

This is my nginx version

```
root@h2456595:~# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.13.8
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --modules-path=/usr/share/nginx/modules --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-ipv6 --with-file-aio --with-http_v2_module --with-compat --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --add-dynamic-module=/usr/share/passenger/ngx_http_passenger_module
```

**I had tried to configure the `nginx.conf` by `proxy_pass`, but still, it didn't work and also I'm not having `httpd.conf` instead `apache2.conf`**

**How should I need to modify which configuration files needed to modify in order to work correctly?**